# Online Video Lectures for Graduate Level Mathematics?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, education

I am wondering if there is a nice compilation of good video lectures in graduate level mathematics? I mean a website, or a forum, or maybe something like course-era (which is mostly undergraduate level)  that gathers links to exceptional lectures that have been video-taped all around the world?

If not, can we do it ourselves somehow? Maybe make a forum or something. Or do it right here, I don't know... If you know a specific lectures series about a specific area of mathematics share the link with the rest of us. There are a lot of these videos for undergraduate mathematics, but not so much for graduate math.

I, personally, am desperately looking for a nice video lecture on algebraic geometry, representation theory, quantum groups, enumerative combinatorics and... much more...

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/54430/video-lectures-of-mathematics-courses-available-online-for-free

Comment: oh awesome I guess I'll remove this then